# Open .img file to mod a software

Tags: windows, images, img

I'd like to open .img files which I suppose to be pictures (there are many .img in a subfolder of this program: lobby.img, avatars.img, cards.img etc).

I wanted to change a background in this software since it really hurts my eyes after several minutes in fron of pc, it's too bright and colorful.

However I don't know how to open those .img files: I've first tried with paint and some others image editors, but after I've googled a little bit I've discovered that .img refers to: "binary files with .img filename extension that store raw disk images of floppy disks, hard drives, or optical discs."

I've tried to open it with 7z but it doens't work either.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

P.S.
It's essential to me to use this software, and if I can't manage to change those backgrounds I'll probably have to buy another monitor...

Comment: usually .img is associated with disk images, not with pictures, but your filenames do indicate that that may not be accurate in this case, and that your program handles the filetype differently than most programs would when opening an .img. It is also possible that they are just containers, so you could try opening them with a virtual disk mounter like virtualcloneCD or daemon tools. That means though, that most applications that do know .imgs as a disk image type will not recognize the internal structure of these files. if you tell us the name of the software, we may be able to tell you more.

Comment: Use a hex editor like HxD to open the IMG file and look at the first four to eight bytes and see if matches the file signature for any known image formats. Alternatively, use [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) to identify the files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: I've used TrID to identify it and it happened to be a .CEL file (Autodesk FLIC image file). Any ideas on how can I handle it?

Comment: Was it a 100% match? What percentage of similarity to the Autodesk FLIC format did TrID report?

Comment: Yes it was a 100% match. I've tried to modify the extension of the file to .cel then to open it with GiMP but it failed.

Comment: Update: I've repeated the process to make sure there was a 100% match. And actually there was a 100% match just with 1 file: avatars.img. But other files .img in the same folder couldn't be recognized.

Maybe a clue could be the folder name: gfx; it means nothing to me but maybe it does to you!

Comment: That information doesn't help much. If you could let us know the name of program you're trying to modify, add a few screenshots and also post a few of those IMG files, maybe someone can take a look.

Comment: @Vinayak you can't donwload the software without having an account; however I've downloaded the .img files here if you'd like to have a look! https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxENJdqZ02Q0LUNRZVZGVEpxZXc&usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

```
NOTE: This is not an answer to the question, but a description of some of my findings
```

From what I can tell, the files are a custom archive format and they're probably compressed using [DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) since compressing them using ZIP didn't change the filesizes much while compressing using RAR, did.

Each file looks like it starts with the file signature `32 30 53 52` followed by what looks like a listing of the files contained within the archive. 42 bytes after each file name string looks like they might contain information about how the files are stored in the structure.

```
32 30 53 52 09 00 00 00 74 61 62 6C 65 31 2E 70 20SR....table1.p
6E 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ng̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.
BD 12 03 00 3C 04 03 00 DC 01 00 00 74 61 62 6C ̲½̲.̲.̲.<̲.̲.̲.̲Ü̲.̲.̲.tabl
65 32 2E 70 6E 67 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e2.png̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.
00 00 00 00 BD 12 03 00 3C 04 03 00 18 06 03 00 ̲.̲.̲.̲.̲½̲.̲.̲.<̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.̲.
```

You might get a better answer at [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

---

**EDIT:** I found out later that 42 bytes are not always used to (possibly) represent information about the archived file since the length of the zeroes preceding the non zero bytes varies from one IMG file to another.

However, I found out that 12 bytes preceding a filename string are always non-zero (ending with a null byte). In the above example, they'd be `BD 12 03 00 3C 04 03 00 DC 01 00 00` and `BD 12 03 00 3C 04 03 00 18 06 03 00` respectively.

As an alternative solution, I'd suggest that you use a software program like [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) that attempts to adjust the color temperature of the computer's display according to the time of day to make it easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

The ".img" extension can be put on a file with any format whatsoever. Only the creators
of the file know what's in there, so ask them. The file content may well be obfuscated, and  require proprietary deobfuscation software to see what's in there. As a last resort, you could open the file with a hex editor to look for clues.